# Storing foreign language characters in mysql resultes in question marks

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, utf-8, collation

I am storing non-English characters in a MySQL data base for example: الجزائر

Unfortunately these characters get stored in my database and get displayed as questions marks like this:

> ??????

I am using CodeIgniter active record as my Database abstraction layer and I have my database collation set as `utf8_unicode_ci`.

How can I store the characters properly using MySQL?

Comment: Did you check your table collation only? You need to check collation of the fields also.

Comment: You should have store it at collation set as utf8_general_ci or utf8mb4_general_ci for both table and field.

Comment: In fact I only changed the field collation... not the table collation... hmmm.

Comment: I did not know about the table collation.... so I have to set both the table and the field collation to utf8_general_ci?

Comment: Yes. then try gain

Comment: Try to set collation utf8mb4_general_ci

Comment: Nope, not working.

Comment: It's just refusing to work... I set both the table and the field to utf8mb4_general_ci. Very frustrating.

Comment: This problem is usually due to a setting in MySQL that does not match the settings for the application program or the operating system. Here are some common steps for correcting these types of issues:

This is copy of beginning explanation here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-cjk.html#faq-cjk-why-cjk-question-marks

Comment: Hmm... tried adding default_charset = "UTF-8" & mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8 to my php ini, tried adding `'dbcollat' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci'` to by database config file... tried changing my MySQL collation and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst - See "question mark" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored for likely causes and cures.

Comment: @KorayKüpe - Only the "encoding" (`CHARACTER SET`) is a problem; sort order (`COLLATION`) is irrelevant for this Question.

Comment: The _database_ settings (charset & collation) are only _defaults_ for tables.  The _table_ settings are only _defaults_ for columns.  You must look at `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see what you really have.

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst - How are you "storing" those characters?  Via Java?  HTML form?  PHP?  phpmyadmin?  Something else?  The problem is likely to be there.

Comment: @Rick James, thanks for the comments... I am storing the data via an HTML form. The form data is handled by codeigniter and I used phpmyadmin to set up my database.

Comment: Look for the "character encoding" when running the form.  Look at "view source"; is there a `meta` tag at the top, are any attributes on the `form` tag?

Comment: My HTML template has <meta charset="utf-8"> on the top... the form tag only has an id, action and a method attribute.